# What does the expression "Brothers in Arms" mean?

Tags: lyrics

I was listening to Dire Straits and wondered what "brothers in arms" are...

Comment: Also **brother of arms** and **brother at arms**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Brothers in arms are soldiers fighting on the same side of some conflict.

Here, *brothers* is not used literally but to mean "ally" or "comrade". The *in arms* part refers to the fact that they are soldiers, *arms* meaning "weaponry".

Comment: Why does *arms* mean "weaponry"?

Comment: *Arms* is a shortened form of the word [armaments](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/armament), which is simply a synonym for weapon. Since English has both French and German roots, *weapon* comes from German whereas *armament* comes from French.

Answer (score 15):

It's referring to [fellow combatants or soldiers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brother-in-arms).

> Through these fields of destruction
>   Baptisms of fire
>  
>   I've witnessed your suffering
>  
>   As the battles raged higher
>  
>   And though they hurt me so bad
>  
>   In the fear and alarm
>  
>   You did not desert me
>  
>   My brothers in arms

It is ostensibly a song about camaraderie in war, but it could be metaphorical (as is so often the case with songs and poetry)

Answer (score 7):

It means fellow soldiers.

Maybe not always in a military sense, but since soldiers have to rely on their colleagues, it can mean someone you trust in any situation where there is opposition.

Answer (score 5):

*Brothers-in-arms* simply means *comrades* or *comrades-in-arms*. *-In-arms* is synonymous with *in battle*, *at war*, etc... (literally or figuratively). By and large, the term evokes solidarity, especially in a struggle.

> **comrade** (*noun*)<sup>[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comrade?region=us)</sup>
>
> a companion who shares one's activities or is a fellow member of an organization.
>
> - (also **comrade-in-arms**)a fellow soldier or serviceman.
> - a fellow socialist or communist (often as a form of address).

Answer (score 2):

You are all leaving out the intentional nuance of increased trust and bonding.

Comrades in arms are one level, but Brothers in arms are a much greater level of trust and confidence. These nuances are important.

Answer (score 2):

No answer to this question can possibly be complete without a reference to Shakespeare's **[St. Crispins's Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Crispin%27s_Day_Speech)** speech by *Henry V* (my emphasis):

> We few, we happy few, we band of **brothers**;
>    For he to-day that sheds his blood with me
>    Shall be my **brother**; be he ne’er so vile,
>    This day shall gentle his condition;
>    And gentlemen in England now-a-bed
>    Shall think themselves accurs’d they were not here,
>    And hold their manhoods cheap whiles any speaks
>    That fought with us upon Saint Crispin’s day.

Answer (score 0):

Brothers in arms does not refer only to soldiers on the same side. It refers to all of the combatants as the line "We are fools to make war on our brothers in arms" points out.

Comment: There is historical evidence that agrees with this, but you should provide the reference along with your answer. Where did that quote come from.

Comment: Always check your sentences for proper capitalization, spelling, punctuation, grammar and style before posting the answer.